# Unable to install quick.db (some type of problem with better-sqlite3)

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So recently I wanted to make a new discord.js bot. I made a new folder, ran "npm i discord.js" and other modules. Then I typed "npm i quick.db". Thats a module im very familiar with and wanted to use it, but then this showed up:

```
PS C:\Users\Boris\Documents\CTW Bot> npm i quick.db

> better-sqlite3@7.4.4 install C:\Users\Boris\Documents\CTW Bot\node_modules\better-sqlite3
> prebuild-install || npm run build-release

prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=17.1.0 runtime=node arch=x64 libc= platform=win32)

> better-sqlite3@7.4.4 build-release C:\Users\Boris\Documents\CTW Bot\node_modules\better-sqlite3
> node-gyp rebuild --release


C:\Users\Boris\Documents\CTW Bot\node_modules\better-sqlite3>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\Boris\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild --release )  else (node "C:\Users\Boris\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild --release )
gyp ERR! find VS 
gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version was set from command line or npm config
gyp ERR! find VS - looking for Visual Studio version 2015
gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
gyp ERR! find VS - not found
gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
gyp ERR! find VS 
gyp ERR! find VS valid versions for msvs_version:
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS 
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Users\Boris\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Boris\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Users\Boris\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:351:14)        
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Boris\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:70:14
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Boris\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:372:16
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Boris\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Boris\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:404:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1062:16)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Boris\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Boris\Documents\CTW Bot\node_modules\better-sqlite3
gyp ERR! node -v v17.1.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! better-sqlite3@7.4.4 build-release: `node-gyp rebuild --release`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the better-sqlite3@7.4.4 build-release script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Boris\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-11-18T20_01_38_296Z-debug.log
npm WARN ctw-bot@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN ctw-bot@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! better-sqlite3@7.4.4 install: `prebuild-install || npm run build-release`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the better-sqlite3@7.4.4 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Boris\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-11-18T20_01_39_061Z-debug.log
```

Now I mentioned installing discordjs... Thats because my last use with discord.js was version 12 (or 11, but not 13) and so when I installed it, it came with version 13. I go ahead and run "node ." before all of the modules being installed (excluding discord.js), just to see the bot online and it tells me something along the lines:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'node:events'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Boris\Documents\CTW Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\BaseClient.js
```

Turns out I gotta update node.js
So I do. From node.js version 12 I go all the way to 17 which is a pretty big leap. The problem goes away and everyone is fine. Then I go ahead and install quick.db..... and yeah you know the rest. What should I do???

Answer (score 0):

The error
better-sqlite3 error is caused due to the installation was not correctly done!
Try reinstalling the program

The second one is also the same thing

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I tried reinstalling the modules, but the quick.db and better-sqlite3 (I tried individually but it still didnt work) still gave me this error. What I decided to do is delete nodejs and reinstall nodejs ver 16 instead of 17 and then reinstalled discord.js version 12 and now it works perfectly. One slight problem tho... all of the errors I get, stop the bot. Even if its a missing perms error. I dont know why, its kinda frustrating but I just decided to put "catch()" to everything and voila everything is ok.